# Sort Telerik RadGrid for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, radgrid

What is the way to sort Telerik's RadGrid ? I don't want to add a form server tag, and I don't want to use a user control with code behind like an example I've seen (since I think these are not true MVC solutions, am I right ?).
Please point me to an example or post example code...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a good example with code at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/sorting/defaultcs.aspx.  It looks like they are using tags, so if you want to do it some other way, your best bet is to ask them.  I've heard they have really good support.

Answer (score 0):

For your telerik questions you should go to http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx

Their support is great and if the forums don't cut it just send a formal request, you will need to create a demo project with your problem.  I have used telerik products for years and they never fail to answer your question within a few days.

The demo site is also a great source of knowledge (linked above by robert)

Guido

Answer (score 0):

I am using the ASP.NET MVC open source Telerik controls.  Here is an example of how I'm using the sort.  It works for server control or Ajax but I've found that the Ajax grid is more touchy as far as it creating circular reference errors.

This Ajax example sorts by two columns.  The logic is the same for server binding.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.category_id ))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
    .Select("AjaxGridSelect", "CategoryTree")
    .Insert("GridInsert", "CategoryTree", new { GridEditMode.PopUp, GridButtonType.ImageAndText })
    .Update("GridUpdate", "CategoryTree", new { GridEditMode.InLine, GridButtonType.ImageAndText })
    .Delete("GridDelete", "CategoryTree", new { GridEditMode.InLine, GridButtonType.ImageAndText }))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.category_name).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.status_cd).Width(100);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
            commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
        }).Width(180).Title("Commands");
    })
     .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
           .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(50)
           .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric)
           .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
           .Sortable(o => o.OrderBy(sortcol => 
              {
                    sortcol.Add(a => a.category_name);
                    sortcol.Add(a => a.add_date);
              })
           .Filterable()
           .Groupable()
           .Selectable())
```